# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on segue into tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, iboutlet

I have the following two controllers:
1)

```
class DataViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!
    var dataObject: String = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.dataLabel!.text = dataObject
    }

}
```

and 2)

```
class HubListController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"

    var token: String = ""
    var userId: Int = 0

    var work: Array<AnyObject> = ["1", "2", "3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      print("getting count: \(self.work.count)")
      return self.work.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Foo"
        return cell
    }
    // MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
}
```

I then have a button on the first View that segues to the second view, immidiatly causing a crash with

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Using the debugger to inspect, it turns out that `tableView` is nil. Why? And how can I get this (trivial) example to work?

Comment: Double check that you have connected the tableview object in your storyboard scene to the tableview IBOutlet. Also you can set up the delegate, data source and register the cell reuse identifier right in the IB scene too. Finally, your title says "tableview patroller" but your class is a UIViewController subclass. A UITableViewController has the tableview as its root view in the scene and automatically connects the tableview outlet. With a UIViewController you need to connect the tableview manually and the root view is typically a UIView

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: In Interface Builder, select the tableview and in the inspector on the right drag from "new referencing outlet" to your viewcontroller object and the select the tableview outlet

Comment: thank you so much. If you write up an answer, I'll upvote/accept it. One question, for future reference, is there a way to do this purely programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create all of the view objects programmatically rather than using storyboard scenes. Some people prefer this but personally I find it way too painful and almost always use storyboards. If you use storyboards then you have to make the connection in IB. (I guess you could set a tag on the object in IB and then traverse the view hierarchy to find that object but that is even worse)